# Adding values to database table only once

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I have to create a cart application in Spring MVC.
I have this cartentries table in database, where I store book_id,id_cartEntry and other fields. Also I have an user table, where I store id_user. I have similar entries in my cartentries, and when I click the checkout button, those entries have to be loaded into a cart table.
The problem is that I don't know how to store the id_user field into a variable, so that I do not have to have this line of code:

```
while (resultSet2.next())
```

This is making my code execute only once, so that only one entry from cartentries is loaded into the cart table. This is because the resultSet2 doesn't find any more new users in the table, because I am logged into a single user. How can I make all data from cartentries go into cart table?

This is the function:

```
   @RequestMapping("/checkout")
    public void checkout(@RequestParam String username) {
        System.out.println("this is checkout from book controller");
        System.out.println("username is " + username);
        Connection connection = ConnectToDatabase.createConnection();
        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("select * from cartentries");
            ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

            PreparedStatement preparedStatement2 = connection.prepareStatement("select id_user from user where username='" + username + "'");
            ResultSet resultSet2 = preparedStatement2.executeQuery();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                while (resultSet2.next()) {
                    PreparedStatement preparedStatement1 = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO cart(id_user,id_cartEntry,totalPrice)VALUES(?,?,?)");
                    preparedStatement1.setInt(1,resultSet2.getInt("id_user"));
                    preparedStatement1.setInt(2, resultSet.getInt("id_cartEntry"));
                    preparedStatement1.setInt(3, resultSet.getInt("totalPrice"));
                    preparedStatement1.executeUpdate();
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: ...Why not JPA!! you can do that in one shot

Comment: @YCF_L and how can I do that?

Comment: @YCF_L maybe he is starting with Java? +1 Hibernate/JPA way.

Comment: @admlz635, I don't know how to use them and I just want this simple thing... To get the id of the username and to store it into a variable, so that I could insert data into cart table...

Answer (score 0):

I've change your code to "store" the userid if it was found.

```
    try {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("select * from cartentries");
        ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement2 = connection.prepareStatement("select id_user from user where username=?");

        preparedStatement2.setString(1, username);
        ResultSet resultSet2 = preparedStatement2.executeQuery();


        PreparedStatement preparedStatement1 = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO cart(id_user,id_cartEntry,totalPrice)VALUES(?,?,?)");

        Integer userId;
        if (resultSet2.next()) {
            // guess it found at least one user
            userId = resultSet2.getInt("id_user");
        }

        if (userId != null) {
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                preparedStatement1.setInt(1, userId);
                preparedStatement1.setInt(2, resultSet.getInt("id_cartEntry"));
                preparedStatement1.setInt(3, resultSet.getInt("totalPrice"));
                preparedStatement1.executeUpdate();
            }
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I've also change your userid query to use setString instead of concatenation. See *SQLInjection*

Maybe you can refactor those statements into separated methods for better code reading.

PS. Don't forget to add a finally clause and close the connection (or the try-with-resources) to prevent having a resource leaking on database server.

Comment: Thanks @admlz635! And how can I check for duplicates in the cart table before inserting?

Comment: Can you check that before insert on cartentries table? I mean, why you could have duplicate entries on that table?

Comment: @admIz635, well that checkout funtion is linked to a button, that is why it will create duplicates at pushing the button more than once. That is why I need to check for duplicates in the cart table

Comment: I think you can check inside the function/method that do the insert, if the item is already in the cart do nothing, otherwise insert it. Maybe adding a quantity field (on cartentries)? That way does not matter how many times you press the button, if that item is in the cart, just do +1 on the quantity field.